# Pandas object could not convert string to float

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, dataframe

I got some depth image data in csv format.

I want to convert the data into float type so I can reshape them to
image

and I get this error
[image]

my code is like this (I excluded the variables that includes my directory)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# The name of the column I want to convert is "data"
df = pd.read_csv(img)
dat_float = df['data'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(',','').replace('[','').replace(']','')).astype('float')
print(dat_float)
```

My dataframe is like this
[image]

since this is hard to see so I pull out the data I need

[image]

The target to change to float from object is the data (right one to the 'seq')

Comment: you also need to remove the spaces. And I'd suggest to do all in 1 step with the `re` module

Comment: Try to write `pd.read_csv('img.csv')`

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew Thank you for the answer but I have multiple directories to call so that's why I'm using a variable in pd.read_csv()

Comment: @JeromeAtanasio I updated my solution to incoropate the edits to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# create sample data
data = "0;[0,0,13,3,2,251,2,252]"
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=";", header=None)
df.columns = ['seq', 'data']

# convert object to list
df.data=df.data.apply(lambda s: [float(x.strip(' []')) for x in s.split(',')])

# optional: explode to rows
df.explode('data')
```

Answer (score 0):

For the part that you need to turn your string into float, here's how you can do it. I just make myself a dataframe with a list of strings.

```
data = {'seq': [1,2],
        'data':[['0','0','0','0','0'],['0','0','0','0','0']]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

   seq             data
0    1  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1    2  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

And by using list comprehension, you can get what you need.

```
df['data']=[[float(x) for x in i] for i in df['data']]

   seq                       data
0    1  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
1    2  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```